# How do i add elements to my ArrayList one after the other?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Basically i have this code that's supposed to do this: Each time i call getAddedInvoices it's gonna add another element to the list, but my problem is that i'm new to the ArrayList so i'm not sure about how the thing works and it keeps adding elements like on top of each other instead of one after the other, This is the Code:

```
List<InvoiceData> data = new ArrayList<InvoiceData>();

public List<InvoiceData> getAddedInvoices() {
    int f=0;
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    String jsonString = ReadingURL("http://pos.avancari.co.cr/app/buscar.productos.php");
    try{
        JSONArray jsonItems = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        for(int i =0; i<jsonItems.length();i++){
            if(jsonItems.getJSONObject(i).getString("itemCode").equals(addedcode)){
                InvoiceData row = new InvoiceData();
                row.id = addedcant;
                row.invoiceNumber = i;
                row.productName = jsonItems.getJSONObject(i).getString("itemDesc");
                row.productCode = jsonItems.getJSONObject(i).getString("itemCode");
                row.precio = jsonItems.getJSONObject(i).getString("itemPrice");
                data.add(row);
                f++;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("No entra a condicional con: "+addedcode);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

That was the function, and then i just call it like this:

```
Invoices invoices = new Invoices();
List<InvoiceData> data = invoices.getAddedInvoices();
```

It's adding the selected elements correctly but idk why it just holds one and just replaces it with the new one instead of keep adding them.
Thanks in Advance

*Edit: The problem is that in the "if", even if it goes 5 fives times doesn't detect that it's another add apparently, because i added another data.add and this time i got size: 2 (which i didn't have before, it just said 1)

Comment: Did you override the equals method in InvoiceData

Comment: I am not sure I follow 100%, but it might be due to the fact that you are creating a new list each time --> `List<InvoiceData> data = new ArrayList<InvoiceData>();`. This will discard the previous list and you would need to start from scratch.

Comment: @npinti Yeah i thought about that and made it global so i can just add the data, but it's giving me the same problem

Comment: @marcramser No i haven't, i'm not sure what you by that though, i'm fairly new at this kind of projects

Comment: If you do `Invoices invoices = new Invoices();` each time, you will start from scratch each time.

Comment: @npinti yeah i already made it global, but it's giving me the same thing

Comment: Aren't you just mistaking you global "data" for the local variable "data" that is inside your getAddedInvoices method ?

Comment: i don't think so, when i click on the word data, it marks the List data i'm trying to use!

Comment: Does it affect that the List is being used in another screen/class, then closes to add the data from another screen/class, and then opens again? i think it should be completely fine since my class Invoices creates kind of a bridge between them but maybe it does have to do with the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion, make getAddedInvoices as void return type, do not return the data as its already global.

In this line you are reassigning which can be a problem.
List data = invoices.getAddedInvoices();

Since "data" is already global, just use it after invoices.getAddedInvoices() is called instead of getting a return value assigned again.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue, if I understand what you want, is that you overwrite your data everytime you call your method.
Since java methods pass non-primitive objects by reference, you can do like this :

```
//In your target class or as a field
List<InvoiceData> data = new ArrayList<InvoiceData>();

// That's another method
public void addInvoices(ArrayList<InvoiceData> pData) {
    int f=0;
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    String jsonString = 
        ReadingURL("http://pos.avancari.co.cr/app/buscar.productos.php");
    try{
        JSONArray jsonItems = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        for(int i =0; i<jsonItems.length();i++){
            if(jsonItems.getJSONObject(i).getString("itemCode").equals(addedcode)){
                InvoiceData row = new InvoiceData();
                row.id = addedcant;
                row.invoiceNumber = i;
                row.productName = jsonItems.getJSONObject(i).getString("itemDesc");
                row.productCode = jsonItems.getJSONObject(i).getString("itemCode");
                row.precio = jsonItems.getJSONObject(i).getString("itemPrice");
                pData.add(row);
                f++;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("No entra a condicional con: "+addedcode);
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then call it like this :

```
invoices.addInvoices(data);
```

Comment: as i said in the comments: Does it affect that the List is being used in another screen/class, then closes to add the data from another screen/class, and then opens again? i think it should be completely fine since my class Invoices creates kind of a bridge between them but maybe it does have to do with the problem

Comment: Well it's designed to be called from other classes. But, if by screen you mean activity, then it's another issue. The instances of your activity might be destroyed if you start another one or if the configuration changes.

Comment: Oh that's a bummer, i did meant activity, i usually worked with InvoiceData[] and the data is working fine between activities, but in this case i don't have an specific length so i had to use this,

Comment: To my knowledge, there shouldn't be any difference using arrays or arrayLists regarding activities. Did you make any design change ?

Comment: Yeah but unlike Arrays, ArrayLists don't need the specific lenght, and that's what i need, because i don't know how much i'll add